# HA Proxy ACL for URL matching dynamically

Tags: haproxy

Recently I have gone through HA Proxy ACL details and need help with a specific scenario. My scenario is given below.

My URL's will be like **https://companyName.research.com/index**. Company name is dynamic today I have 2 companies and later it may reach to hundred.In the ACL section it normally checks in URL that if any particular String exist or not and according to that forward to back end. This configurations are not dynamic. Like I have one URL start with blog then will forward it to blog back end. But my scenario is completely different. Here system will check is any company name exist or not if exist then it will forward the request to the back end with that company name dynamically. Like if company **dummy** given forward it to **dummy**. But as I said company names are not known to me so, it's ha proxy which will fetch the company name from url and will find the suitable backend with name matching and will forward. Is that possible with HA Proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved through HAProxy ACL. In has 2 section, fronted and backend. In frontend redirection

Frontend:
   acl is_valid_base_domain hdr_end(host) -i mydomain.com
   use_backend BE:subs-%[req.hdr(host),lower,field(1,'.')] if is_valid_base_domain

This checks if the domain belongs to mydomain and if yes then take the same. Example: one.mydomain.com. In this case it will fetch the domain name "one" and will redirect to BE:subs-one backend.

Define a backend BE:subs-one

You are ready to go.